# VNC Viewer Authentication Failure

Tags: pi-3, vnc

I have set up and connected with VNC Viewer in the past and it has worked fine.

I have recently changed my Raspberry Pi login password from "raspberry" to something more specific and now when I try to connect the VNC I get an "Authentication Failure" message.

I originally followed these steps to set it up and it worked fine.

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-control-your-raspberry-pi-from-any-computer-usin-1788592777

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening or what I might be doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a terminal to log in with SSH?  https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/unix.md

Comment: Yes SSH works fine

Answer (score 4):

Use the command `vncpasswd` [(man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vncpasswd).

It appears that you can change the VNC password by way of the VNC Server desktop app. If you can log into the Pi using an actual monitor, then get X running (`startx`), open the VNC Server app, go to Options, then Users and Permissions, click on Password, and confirm a new password to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually use `RealVNC` which I guess from the link you posted you do.

I use `tightvncserver`, and the first time you use it you run `vncpasswd`which stores encrypted password in `~.vnc/passwd`.

I assume `RealVNC` is similar.

Comment: I tried tightvncserver and ended up with the same authentication failure.

Do I need to replace the ~.vnc/passwd or delete it? How do you suggest I fix this?

Comment: @DNavarro It won't hurt to delete it, as it should be re-created. You really need to read the `RealVNC` documentation, although I find it rather convoluted. The other suggestion is to turn `VNC` off, delete `~.vnc/passwd` (or `~.vnc/`) and turn `VNC` on, which will hopefully re-create the password.

Comment: DNavarro, I have the same problem. Please can you tell me how you got it to work ?