# Multiple VNC Servers (Touchscreen)

Tags: vnc

I am using a RaspberryPi (3B+) with the official 7" touch screen. I have VNC installed and connecting to it works with the touch screen resolution 800 x 480 (I am getting a copy of what I see on the touch screen)
In order to code on that machine, it would be nice to have a higher resolution screen. So I start a second vncserver with

```
vncserver -geometry 1024x800
```

and the pi responds with

> New desktop is *name*:2 (*xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx*:2)

I can connect to that VNC server, but I fail to log in. I tried the same username/password as the touchscreen VNC (:0) and many other u/p combination. Can anybody tell me what defines username and password for that second VNC server?

Answer (score 0):

RealVNC by default allows access to the existing GUI screen using the normal password. (AFAIK this requires the RealVNC viewer.)

RealVNC, in conjunction with most other flavours, allows the creation of additional virtual sessions (resources permitting).

All of these sessions permit any user to login. Most VNC servers require you to set a password for the VNC session - this is independent of the normal login password; See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61514/8697

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did. I use RealVNC to access the Touchscreen GUI. I start a virtual screen with the command written above. But I fail to connect to it. I set the password with vncpasswd, but I fail to enter the correct password. The password for the Touchscreen GUI fails.